# Pause AVAudioPlayer when external audio is playing

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm currently facing a problem and I'll be glad if some of you being trough this problem and came up with a simple solution.

So basically, the question is:
**Is there any way that I can pause an ongoing AVAudioPlayer when some external sounds come in such as: music, incoming call, notifications, etc.**

I know that for detecting a call, there's this new CXCallObserverDelegate that helps us, but for music and the rest is there any simple solution to resolve all of this?

In terms of code, everything works fine, there's not a single problem regarding playing the audio. I have a custom path and an error, the error returns nil.

`NSError *avPlayerError = nil;
    NSData* mp3Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path options: NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error: &avPlayerError];`

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using this code for my application :

in AppDelegate , `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add Observer for any incoming interrupt

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onAudioSessionEvent(noti:)), name: Notification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
```

When any interrupt occurs this function will called

```
@objc func onAudioSessionEvent(noti:Notification){
    if noti.name == Notification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption
    {
        if let value = noti.userInfo![AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? NSNumber {
            if value.uintValue == AVAudioSessionInterruptionType.began.rawValue {
                print("start interrupt")


            }else{
                print("end interrupt")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it :)